# Coloring of unordered list in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to color the unordered list differently as the body background but it does not work

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        body {
            background-image: url("img.png");
        {
        ul{
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
        <title>
            Dragon baby
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>Recipe1: cookies</li>
            <li>Recipe2: bakery</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We need more information about what exactly you're trying to do. If you want to toggle the color of the links you can create two css classes and toggle them programatically.

Comment: If the case is like you want different color for each li, you can use the nth child selector to style each li differently - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your style.

```
    <style>
        body {
            background-image: url("img.png");
        {
        ul{
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
```

After your background image, you have an open curly bracket instead of a closing bracket. I tested the following and it works:

```
    <style>
        body {
            background-image: url("img.png");
        }
        ul{
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
```